# How do I create different colours/rules to links on the same page in CSS on a separate file that is consistant in the five main browsers?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I want to create different colours/rules for different links on the same page in a separate css file. The file is already linked to the page in concern. I tried many different ways to apply the different rules to the links and they either apply one set of rules to the whole page, the default settings apply and cancel out the changes or only some of the rules apply.

The first set of links are the specific ones I want for certain areas of the page.

```
a#mainnav, #categories:link { color: grey; text-decoration: none;}

a#mainav, #categories, #header, #bottombar:visited { color: darkcyan; font-weight: normal;}

a#mainnav, #categories:focus { color: lightgrey;}

a#mainnav:hover { color: darkgrey;}

a#categories:hover { color: darkgrey; font-size: 18;}

a#mainnav, #categories:active { color: silver;}
```

The second set of rules are the ones I want to apply to everything else on the page.

```
a#header, #bottombar:link { color: deepskyblue; text-decoration: none;}

a#header, #bottombar:focus { color: darkcyan;}

a#header, #bottombar:hover { color: mediumblue;}

a#header, #bottombar:active { color: royalblue;}
```

I've tried .header and #header. I've tried `#header`, `#bottombar` and `#header` `#bottombar`. Also tried before the a: and after the a as you can see. Nothing seems to work they never seem to adopt the separate rules in the specified areas.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container"> 
    <div id="header" title="U BLOSH"> 
        <h1>
            <a name="index.html"</a>
            <a href="#index.html" 
            <abbr title="You Buy Low or Sell High"</abbr> 
            <img src="file:///C|/Users/Marcus/Pictures/ubloshlogo.png" alt="logo" width="250" height="50";</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: <div id="header" title="U BLOSH"> <h1><a name="index.html"</a><a href="#index.html" <abbr title="You Buy Low or Sell High"</abbr>
   <img src="file:///C|/Users/Marcus/Pictures/ubloshlogo.png" alt="logo" width="250" height="50";</h1>
  </div><div id="mainnav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#buy">Buy</a></li>
   <li><a href="#sell">Sell</a></li>
   <li><a href="#myublosh">My U BLOSH</a></li>
   <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
   <li><a href="#whatisublosh">What is U BLOSH</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

Comment: There are lots of problems with that markup.

Comment: @Marcus You should edit your original question rather than post it as a comment. Also, check out the W3C spec on pseudo-elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes

Comment: @Jezen it won't allow me to post the whole html so I've posted the relevant code for the header and mainnav sections

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd be hard for anyone to say this without coming across as condescending, but you really need to study up on very basic HTML and CSS. You actually need to close your tags properly.

This line: `<a name="index.html"</a>`

**Incorrect.** You need to close the opening tag like this: `<a name="index.html"></a>`. Also, what does the `name` attribute do? An anchor tag (`a`) should link somewhere. You link it somewhere with the `href` attribute.

This line: `<a href="#index.html"`

**Incorrect.** Again, you didn't close your tag. You included an `href` this time, but where is it supposed to lead to? Do you have an element on the same page with an `ID` of `index.html`? I don't think so.

This line: `<abbr title="You Buy Low or Sell High"</abbr>`

**Incorrect.** What are you meant to be abbreviating? You included your title, but you didn't finish the opening tag. If you want to abbreviate the phrase 'You Buy Low or Sell High', it would probably look like `<abbr title="You Buy Low or Sell High">YBLOSH</abbr>`.

This line: `<img src="file:///C|/Users/Marcus/Pictures/ubloshlogo.png" alt="logo" width="250" height="50";`

You didn't close the tag. A valid image tag looks like `<img src="" alt="">` (HTML) or `<img src="" alt="" />` (XHTML). What's the semicolon for?

---

As we continue on to your original question on targeting elements with CSS, take the following markup as an example:

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="header">
         <a href="http://somewebsite.com">Some link text</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

In order to target that anchor inside those two `div` elements, you might write something like this:

```
#container #header a {color:red;}
#container #header a {color:blue;}
```

I don't want to write out any more *Hello World* web stuff. [Please, take the time to learn.](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select links *within* `#mainnav` try this: `#mainnav a {...}`, etc

Comment: I've tried that unless you could be more specific like #mainnav a:focus (...} etc as this has been tried to no avail

Comment: I've tried that and it works on everything but the mainnav all the other areas work as they are supposed to. The mainnav is half working but the initial appearance is the browsers default rules until you hover